# How to use React.forwardRef with TypeScript when using different html elements in the render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am struggling with that very simple component that displays a span or a `<br>` depending on the props:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {value: string}

function LetterRenderer({value = ''}: Props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLElement>) {
    switch(value) {
      case '\n': return (<br ref={ref} />);
      default: return (<span ref={ref}>{value}</span>);
    }
}

const Letter = React.forwardRef<HTMLElement, Props>(LetterRenderer);
Letter.displayName = 'Letter';
export default Letter;
```

On `<br ref={ref} />`, the second `ref` is underlined with the following error message:

```
Type 'Ref<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLBRElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLBRElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLBRElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLBRElement> | null | undefined'.
    Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLBRElement>'.
      Property 'clear' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLBRElement'.ts(2322)
lib.dom.d.ts(6336, 5): 'clear' is declared here.
index.d.ts(106, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLBRElement>, HTMLBRElement>'
```

How should I work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function LetterRenderer({value = ''}: Props, ref: React.Ref<HTMLElement>) {
// ...
```

Your ref prop accepts `HTMLElement` but what you really want is `HTMLBRElement | HTMLSpanElement` because `ref` is passed into a `<br>` and `<span>` who's `ref` attribute is `React.Ref<HTMLBRElement>` and `React.Ref<HTMLSpanElement>` respectively.

Change the ref prop to

```
ref: React.Ref<HTMLBRElement | HTMLSpanElement>
```

Note that `HTMLBRElement` and `HTMLSpanElement` both inherit `HTMLElement` but not the other way around; `HTMLElement` does not have `clear` attribute but `HTMLBRElement` does.

#### Update:

Because `<br>`'s and `<span>`'s `ref` attribute accepts only `React.Ref<HTMLBRElement>` and `React.Ref<HTMLSpanElement>` respectively, `ref` needs to be casted inline accordingly.

```
<br ref={ref as React.Ref<HTMLBRElement>} />

<span ref={ref as React.Ref<HTMLSpanElement>}>{text}</span>
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get `Type 'HTMLBRElement | HTMLSpanElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLBRElement'.
        Property 'clear' is missing in type 'HTMLSpanElement' but required in type 'HTMLBRElement'`

Comment: Should I do something like that: `<br ref={(ref as React.RefObject<HTMLBRElement>)}>` ?

Comment: Oh ok. Just a minor addition to that, I think you can at least cast `<br ref={ref as React.Ref<HTMLBRElement>} />` now.

Comment: Let me know if it works so I can edit the answer and have it accepted, thanks!

Comment: Seems ok to me. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer just now. Please correct any issues if present, thanks